# Linux - Open chromium from a script that runs on startup

Tags: python, linux, bash, chromium

I have a bash script that I've defined to run in startup, which runs a python script that waits for a command from another process, and when it gets it, it should open a chromium window with a certain URL.

When I run this script manually it works fine, but when the script runs from startup, I get an error (displayed in syslog):

> Gtk: Can't open display

I guess that's because it's running in a startup mode so it doesn't actually have a display to "lean" on...
I was wondering if there's any way to get this work, anyway?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your overall goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script that runs on startup try `DISPLAY=:0 <command> &`

To clarify `DISPLAY=:0` simply sets which monitor your window opens on with `0` representing the first monitor of the local machine.